# Best way to display the next batch of photos in a 3d carousel?

Tags: image, carousel, 3d, thumb

I have a 3d button that opens a row of curved images that form a circle around the 3d camera:

[image]

[image]

The curved images start to stack one on top of another after reaching a certain number (since they form a circle).

What is the usual way of tackling this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have defined a fixed physical space, you only really have three options:

1) Increase the diameter of the circle - This will enable you to fit in more photos but they will appear to be further away from the 'camera'.

2) Decrease the size of the images - This will enable you to fit in more photos but the photos will be less distinct.

3) Wrap the photos in multiple rows (either in distinct rows or as a spiral) this will enable you to fit in more photos but will result in more complex navigation.

Each one has a trade-off that you will need to assess for it's impact in your particular use-case.

Answer (score 1):

A 3d carousel is not a common interaction on a 2d screen, and it will have difficulties scaling up to show more curved photos.

The only options are to change the diameter/radius to accommodate more photos and/or make the photos smaller.

However, you might want to rethink using a 3D curved carousel due to the complexities involved in showing more photos.

My advice - keep the carousel simple and your users will thank you for it.

Also a more simple carousel interaction will be quicker, easier and cheaper to code and test.